# Comparing 2 lists of objects ignoring order

Tags: c#, mstest

Using MSTest V2 and `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent()` is failing even if both lists contain the same objects:

```
// User-defined object
public class ClientDto
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public decimal RentShare { get; set; }
}


// Test method
var expectedShares = new List<ClientDto>
{
    new ClientDto
    {
        FullName = "Harry Potter",
        RentShare = 500m
    },
    new ClientDto
    {
        FullName = "Ron Weasley",
        RentShare = 300m
    },
};
var actualShares = new List<ClientDto>
{
    new ClientDto
    {
        FullName = "Ron Weasley",
        RentShare = 300m
    },
    new ClientDto
    {
        FullName = "Harry Potter",
        RentShare = 500m
    },
};
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expectedShares, actualShares);
```

Is there anything else that needs to be implemented in the `ClientDto`?

Comment: Try to implement [`IEqualityComparer<ClientDto>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_SequenceEqual__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__) as shown in this example and use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-5.0#definition) after that

Comment: Thanks but would like an answer for `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because class `ClientDto` doesn't implement `IEquatable<ClientDto>` or `IEquatable`, instances are compared using reference equality.

Thus, the instances in the list will fail to compare - even though they contain the same data - because their references are different.

To fix this, just implement `IEquatable<ClientDto>` so that `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent()` can compare the objects correctly:

```
public class ClientDto: IEquatable<ClientDto>
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public decimal RentShare { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(ClientDto? other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
            return true;

        return FullName == other.FullName && RentShare == other.RentShare;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
            return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType())
            return false;
        return Equals((ClientDto) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (FullName.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ RentShare.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(ClientDto? left, ClientDto? right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(ClientDto? left, ClientDto? right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
}
```

(Implementation courtesy of Resharper.)

Note that for recent versions of .Net Core and C#, you can use a `record` instead of a `class`, because a `record` implements `IEquatable` for you (along with a bunch of other things):

```
public record ClientDto
{
    public string  FullName  { get; set; }
    public decimal RentShare { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, I just chucked in the code in `ClientDto` and it worked. So it's either I buy ReSharper or upgrade to C# 9 (currently at C# 7 or 8 I believe). I don't quite understand the code ReSharper generated but will have to read what `IEquatable` is all about.

Comment: @silver If you're using Visual Studio 2019, it can automatically generate `IEquatable` implementation for you, very similar to how Resharper does it.

Comment: Saviour! Will definitely look into the `record` type in the future. For now this answers what I need just in time.